# Why do subsequent Alerts in my react app show the "useCountdown hook timer" from the first Alert shown in a given session?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

My rubber duck isn't giving me the answer. He is usually smarter.

In my Create-React-App I have an alert context and a react component that handles pop-up alerts throughout the app. I'm playing with React Hooks for the first time and trying to get a countdown timer on each Alert.

I wrote a useCountdown hook (code shown below) which works fine on other test components but when I try to use it with my alerts, every single alert in a given session uses the timer value from the very first alert that fired.

In this [screen shot of faulty alerts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maOvy.png), each alert shown has very different countdown values, yet they all show the countdown value of the first alert. The countdown is in the upper right-hand corner.

I've played around with useEffect() to try to resolve this but it has become clear I have a bit more to learn regarding hooks and their scoping.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Eventually, I will style the timer into a little manual dismiss button with the seconds until auto-dismissal shown as the button's text. For now... just in ugly mode.

**useCountdown hook**

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const useCountdown = (m = 1, s = 10) => {
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(m)
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(s)

  useEffect(() => {
    let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (seconds > 0) {
        setSeconds(seconds - 1)
      }
      if (seconds === 0) {
        if (minutes === 0) {
          clearInterval(myInterval)
        } else {
          setMinutes(minutes - 1)
          setSeconds(59)
        }
      }
    }, 1000)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(myInterval)
    }
  })

  const finalSeconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : `${seconds}`

  return `${minutes}:${finalSeconds}`
}

export default useCountdown
```

**Alert Component**

```
import React, { useContext, Fragment } from 'react'
import AlertContext from '../../context/alert/alertContext'
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'
import styled from 'styled-components' // TODO Refactor to styled

// Custom hook to give each Alert a countdown timer
import useCountdown from '../../hooks/useCountdown' // BUG!

const Alerts = () => {
  // const testAlert = {
  //   id: 12345,
  //   title: 'Problem',
  //   color: 'alert-danger',
  //   icon: 'fas fa-exclamation-triangle',
  //   seconds: 20,
  //   msg: ['This is an alert. Testing 123.', 'Auto-dismiss in 20 seconds.'],
  // }

  const alertContext = useContext(AlertContext)
  const { removeAlert } = alertContext

  // ISSUE #32 The initial value gets used through-out session
  const countdown = useCountdown(alert.seconds)

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <TransitionGroup>
        {alertContext.alerts.length > 0 &&
          alertContext.alerts.map((alert) => (
            <CSSTransition key={alert.id} timeout={500} classNames='pop'>
              <div className={`alert ${alert.color}`}>
                <div className='alert-title'>
                  <h1 onClick={() => removeAlert(alert.id)}>
                    <i className={`${alert.icon}`} /> <span className='hide-sm'>{alert.title}</span>
                  </h1>
                  <span className='alert-countdown'>{countdown}</span>
                  <button className='btn btn-link btn-sm alert-btn hide-sm' onClick={() => removeAlert(alert.id)}>
                    <i className='far fa-times-square fa-3x' />
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div className='alert-items'>
                  <ul>
                    {alert.msg.map((item) => (
                      <li key={item}>
                        <i className='fas fa-chevron-circle-right'></i> <span>{item}</span>
                      </li>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </CSSTransition>
          ))}
      </TransitionGroup>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default Alerts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using your `useCountdown` in the `Alerts` *container* component thus storing a **single** state for all of the child elements. Basically, currently you have a single interval and thus a single countdown value that is reused for all the alerts.

If you want for each of the alerts to have a separate state(countdown values), you should extract the Alert UI into a separate component and use the `useCountdown` hook there. Then, refactor the Alerts container component to render an `Alert` component for each instance.

Here is a sample code. It might contain syntax errors because I can't test it right now but try it:

Alerts container component:

```
import React, { useContext, Fragment } from 'react'
import AlertContext from '../../context/alert/alertContext'
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'
import styled from 'styled-components' // TODO Refactor to styled

const Alerts = () => {
  const alertContext = useContext(AlertContext)
  const { removeAlert } = alertContext

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <TransitionGroup>
        {alertContext.alerts.length > 0 &&
          alertContext.alerts.map((alertInstance) => (
              <CSSTransition key={alertInstance.id} timeout={500} classNames='pop'>
                <Alert alert={alertInstance} removeAlert={removeAlert}/>
              </CSSTransition>
          ))}
      </TransitionGroup>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default Alerts
```

Alert Component:

```
export function Alert(props) {
    const countdown = useCountdown(props.alert.seconds);

    return (        
        <div className={`alert ${props.alert.color}`}>
            <div className='alert-title'>
                <h1 onClick={() => props.removeAlert(props.alert.id)}>
                    <i className={`${props.alert.icon}`} /> <span className='hide-sm'>{props.alert.title}</span>
                </h1>
                <span className='alert-countdown'>{countdown}</span>
                <button className='btn btn-link btn-sm alert-btn hide-sm' onClick={() => props.removeAlert(props.alert.id)}>
                    <i className='far fa-times-square fa-3x' />
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className='alert-items'>
                <ul>
                    {props.alert.msg.map((item) => (
                        <li key={item}>
                            <i className='fas fa-chevron-circle-right'></i> <span>{item}</span>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>        
    );
}
```

Also, when altering state that depends on the previous value as in `setMinutes(minutes - 1)` use the updater function instead of simply supplying a value. In this case you ensure that your update will be accurate and not done over stale data thus resulting in wrong state at the end. You can learn more about that here: [useState Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

So your hook should look something like this:

```
const useCountdown = (m = 1, s = 10) => {
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(m)
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(s)

  useEffect(() => {
    let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (seconds > 0) {
        setSeconds((seconds) => seconds - 1)
      }
      if (seconds === 0) {
        if (minutes === 0) {
          clearInterval(myInterval)
        } else {
          setMinutes((minutes) => minutes - 1)
          setSeconds(59)
        }
      }
    }, 1000)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(myInterval)
    }
  })

  const finalSeconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : `${seconds}`

  return `${minutes}:${finalSeconds}`
}
```

Comment: This got me on the right track. Thank you for the very detailed answer. A refactor pulling individual Alerts out of the array and sending them to a second component to handle individual alerts was the fix.

Comment: Also the tip about properly using the useState updater function with a function so I don't trip over stale state was very welcome. I learned that somewhere along the way as I've studied up on hooks but obviously had forgotten. Again thank you for the complete answer. setMinutes((minutes) => minutes - 1) rather than setMinutes(minutes - 1)